# What are the tool that can help me to find non-informative words in documents for classification and eliminate them?

Tags: classification, natural-language

Simply I want to remove words in documents that are not informative for classification purpose instead of biased stop word elimination. Is there any tool that can help me in that way? I know NLTK but it provides a simple stop word eliminator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single *correct* answer to this, but in the past, these are things I had found useful (in different scenarios):

1. Log odds ratio (i.e. how much more frequent is a word in class A than in class B)
2. Eliminating words with low weights assigned by an SVN classifier. This filtering makes sense if you are using a linear kernel, but I am not sure it's correct for other kernels. Also, as far as I can recall, you shouldn't do this if your SVN is using L2 regularization.
3. Simply check the IDF (*inverse document frequency*) value of each word across both classes. Words that belong to too many documents in both classes are not going to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add to the list using part-of-speech tagging and removing uninformative parts of speech.

nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/tagger.shtml

The above site links to an efficient tagger and provides documentation.